# use of https only for certain pages does not work

Tags: ssl, tomcat7

I tried to follow the following stackoverflow answer with no luck
[Use HTTPS only for certain pages in servlet based webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330187/use-https-only-for-certain-pages-in-tomcat-webapp)
Here is what i did, created a self signed cert, installed it in tomcat, my entire website works on https. Then i followed the link above to make my login alone https. When i click on login page, the url takes to https://mywebsite.com:8443/signin.htm. I have started my SSL Connector on 443, why is it trying to connect to 8443?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the redirects in the Connector tag. In server.xml, i had 2 connector, for http(80) and https(443). But the redirect attribute in those connector was set to 8443. I think this means, when the page is on http(80), and according to web.xml we are asking it to goto secure page for example for login then it looks at redirect attribute of http(80) connector. I changed this to 443 and it worked fine.

Comment: Congratulation! If you need anything about SSL Security Certificate, then feel free to contact me. Thanks